# Wireshark capture in Packet tracer

Tags: wireshark, cisco, packet-capture

So after googeling there seem to be a lot of people saying that you cannot capture packets from a simulation in Packet Tracer with Wireshark. However, my prof has given me this as an assignment.

I cannot seem to figure it out.

The Scenario:

2 computers (192.168.1.1 and 192.168.1.2) are linked. I ping from PC 1 ( 192.168.1.1) to PC 2. I want to capture these packets.
How would I go about his?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I know, In Packet Tracer you cannot use Wireshark. You can use Packet Tracer's built in simulation and packet filters to track packets.

Other than Packet Tracer,
There are two solutions to your problem:

1. Physically connect two PCs and just run Wireshark on one PC's network adapter. You can see everything there is between the two of them.
2. Emulators like gns3 provide facility to attach wireshark to Switch/Router interfaces (Network cards), So you can create a scenario in Gns3 with 2 PCs connected by a switch and activate wireshark on one of the switch port.
   Please note that in GNS3 wireshark cannot be attached to the host PC port itself. So that's why we are using an intermediate switch to host wireshark capture.

*Just an advice: Don't use packet tracer, its unreliable and incomplete and sometimes displays or operates wrongly, use emulators like GNS3 which can emulate 99% functionality of routers and connecting network.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply. An hour or so after posting I went to the lab and made the exercise with actual computers.
I am however, required to use PT (We use CISCO networking books)

Comment: Also please be advise that outside your current class or home network, it is completely illegal to use it on a public network or school network. Wireshark is a management tool.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use Packet Tracer with Wireshark because Packet Tracer is just an simulator that you can not connect to other programs, you can use GNS3 because it supports real operating Router systems and Switch Layer 3 and you can connect it to programs such as Wireshark, Nmap and others and you can connect it with local server and virtual devices Such as vmware or VB